# $f(n)=\frac{n^2+2}{1+2^{-n}}$ and $g(n)=n+3$

Tags: functions, inequality, algorithms, computer-science

Given

\begin{aligned}
f(n)&=\frac{n^2+2}{\; 1+2^{-n}}\\[1em] g(n)&=\ \ n+3 
\end{aligned}
I have to calculate the constant $c$ and the $n_0$ of $g(n)=O(f(n))$.

$$n+3≤n^2+3≤3n^2+3≤3n^2+6≤3(n^2+2)$$

At this point I don't know how to go on because if I divide $3(n^2+2)$ by something I get something less than $3(n^2+2)$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT of a possible method: Note that $$\frac{1}{1+2^{-n}} \ge \frac{1}{1+ 2^{-1}} = \frac{2}{3}$$ for all $n \ge 1$. So $f(n) \ge \frac{2}{3}\left(n^2+2\right)$ for all $n\ge 1$. Therefore, it is sufficient for you to find $c$ and $n_0$ such that $$g(n) \le c \times \frac{2}{3}\left(n^2+2\right)$$ for all positive integers $n\ge n_0$. Are you able to do this (note: you have actually already done most of the work for it!)?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: If you know that $g(n)=n+3\le \color{blue}{3}\left(n^2 + 2\right)$, then what happens if you choose $c$ such that $c\times \frac{2}{3} = \color{blue}{3}$? Also note that if $g(n) \le c\times \frac{2}{3}\left(n^2+2\right)$ for some positive constant $c$, then $g(n) \le cf(n)$, because as we said, $ \frac{2}{3}\left(n^2+2\right)\le f(n)$.